# MariaDB//MySql cannot connect to server, cannot seem to start

Tags: mysql, sql, web-services, mariadb

I simply cannot get my MySql server to work or start, no idea what happened, it was running fine.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
[root@OblivionEnt1 jclay]# systemctl start mysqld
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.
[root@OblivionEnt1 jclay]# systemctl status mysqld.server
mysqld.server.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

[root@OblivionEnt1 jclay]# systemctl status mysqld.service
mysqld.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Sep 30 04:12:41 OblivionEnt1 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB database server.
Sep 30 04:12:56 OblivionEnt1 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Sep 30 04:12:57 OblivionEnt1 mysqld_safe[415]: 130930 04:12:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
Sep 30 04:12:57 OblivionEnt1 mysqld_safe[415]: 130930 04:12:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Sep 30 04:12:59 OblivionEnt1 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
Oct 03 22:41:20 OblivionEnt1 mysqld_safe[415]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 176:   579 Killed                  nohup /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-.../mysqld.log 2>&1
Oct 03 22:41:20 OblivionEnt1 mysqld_safe[415]: 131003 22:41:20 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
Oct 03 22:41:20 OblivionEnt1 mysqld_safe[415]: 131003 22:41:20 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
Oct 03 22:41:21 OblivionEnt1 mysqld_safe[415]: 131003 22:41:21 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Oct 05 03:26:38 OblivionEnt1 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB database server.
[root@OblivionEnt1 jclay]#
```